# Querying lat , long from db and show all records with in range

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on program stores latitude and longitude of all users (Using mysql and php).

I need to make query and show list of users within 100 km range.

I am stuck with below issues

1. Db design to get faster result. Is my db structure fine? If i want faster output will index on both lat and long work? Should I use Innodb or myisam engines in below case. Querying result in above said case will take much time if we have hundreds of thousands of records

My sql table structure:

```
id(int 11 primary key auto increment) | lat(varchar) | long(varchar)
```

2. Is there direct sql function or code by which in can get all users with in specified range? I googled and found most of them using cos for this. Is that the only way?

Query which gives output, but is slow:

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM markers 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Comment: ...not to mention trying something and figuring things out for yourself with some code you found but had problems with.

Comment: hey pls read question and check answer , where i can pass lat long

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31628/find-points-within-a-distance-using-mysql

Comment: I have and there's no code for anyone to go on, so it remains unclear and too broad. Go on search engines and/or through Stack and find something related to what you're wanting to achieve. Till then, this is a *"write this for me"* type of question and there are too many possible answers. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MySQL >= 5.6.1, you could use a function `st_distance`, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance

It requires to use `POINT` as the type for the coordinates.

Comment: i do not it what i am looking for